# Optimal betting strategy -- 1D optimization

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, optimization, game-theory

The betting game consists of **two** rounds. In each round you can bet a certain amount, and you know beforehand that the opponent's bet follows a distribution with p.d.f. $f(x)$ whose support is on $[0, \infty)$.

In a round, if your bet is higher you pay whatever the opponent's bet is; otherwise you lose the round and you pay nothing.

Suppose you have $S \in [0, \infty)$ amount of money to bet, and the goal is to win as many rounds as possible with the money in hand (in expectation), under the condition that you cannot spend more than $S$ almost surely.

If you lose the first round, clearly the best strategy is to bet $S$ in the second round, and if you win with a cost of $C$ in the first round, the best strategy is to bet $S - C$ in the second round. Now the problem simply boils down to a 1D optimization problem where the optimization variable is how much you should betin the first round. I'm having a hard time finding the analytical form of the solution.

Comment: "the goal is to win as many rounds as possible": The number of rounds won is a random variable, so it can't be maximized. Do you mean that you want to maximize the expected number of rounds won?

Comment: @joriki Yes, I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to maximize the expected number of rounds won, there’s no point in foregoing a win in the first round to save money hoping for a win in the second round, since that would also just count for one win. Since how much you pay in the first round depends only on whether you win, not on how much you bet in order to win, you should bet the entire sum $S$ in the first round.

Comment: How much you pay in the first round also depends on how much you bet right? i.e., $\int_0^b f(x)dx \cdot \int_0^b xf(x)dx$ in expectation if you bet $b$.

Comment: @YuanGao: Which quantity is given by that expression? If how much you pay in the first round depends on how much you bet (other than through the fact that whether you win depends on your bet), you need to clarify the question accordingly. Currently it seems to rather unambiguously state that "if your bet is higher you pay whatever the opponent's bet is", i.e. what you pay depends only on whether you win, not on how much you bet to win.

Comment: What I was thinking is that the probability of winning under a bet $b$ is $\int_0^b f(x)dx$. And, the expected amount you would pay under the condition that you won under a bet $b$, would be $\int_0^b xf(x)dx$. Maybe I'm wrong somewhere, but I'm not able to see it.

Comment: @YuanGao: No, those are both right, but my argument shows that you don't need those calculations. I don't see how those calculations contradict my argument that how much you pay depends only on whether you win.

Comment: @YuanGao: Actually, they're not quite right – the second one is the unconditional expected payment, not the one conditional on winning – that conditional expectation would be the second integral divided by the first. But, as I said, I don't see how any of that is relevant to my argument, and thus required for the solution.

Comment: @joriki Are you sure this is right? Let's say $f(x)$ equals a sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$ with probability $1$. Then, the expectation of your strategy is $1$, but I think the optimal strategy would be to split over two bets since you can win both rounds. But I could be misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @joriki: Thanks for correcting me. I've updated the post with a direct calculation. It seems solving an equation is needed. I still can't quite get your argument.

Comment: @YuanGao: Unfortunately I still haven't understood which part of it you disagree with. I win if my bet is higher than the other player's bet. If I do win, I pay the other player's bet. Thus, given the other player's bet (which is random but not under our influence), we pay either $0$ or the other player's bet; what we pay depends only on whether we win, that is, on whether our bet is higher than the other player's, and other than that it doesn't depend on our bet. Do you disagree with any of that? If so, please explain with which part, and why.

Comment: @EkeshKumar That does not seem to be valid counterexample. Because even if you bet the full amount in the first around, you would still only pay $\epsilon$ in the first round, and are left with $S - \epsilon$ to bet the second round which would end up winning both rounds.

Comment: This strategy does not quite work if your opponent starts with the exactly the same amount amd follows the same strategy, as neither of you win either round

Comment: @Henry: The opponent doesn't follow the same strategy. It's given that the opponent bets according to a fixed probability density function with support on $[0,\infty]$. Thus the probability that we bet the same amount is zero.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @joriki. I have thought about this answer for a while, and I am convinced that it is correct.